# How to fix a SQL Query for a moving average that doesn't count accurately

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the week **week** number and average time **time**. Sample table data is below.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `week` INTEGER,
  `time` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`week`, `time`)
VALUES
  ('14', '-249'),
  ('15', '-267'),
  ('16', '-254'),
  ('17', '-256'),
  ('18', '-254'),
  ('19', '-262'),
  ('20', '-265'),
  ('21', '-263'),
  ('22', '-258'),
  ('23', '-257'),
  ('24', '-269'),
  ('25', '-278'),
  ('26', '-278'),
  ('27', '-285');
```

I run the following code to get a 4 week moving average based on the data:

```
SELECT week, time, avg(time)
OVER (ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS moving_average
FROM my_table
ORDER BY week ASC
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
   week time moving_average   
    14  -249    -254
    15  -267    -275
    16  -254    -257
    17  -256    -259
    18  -254    -255
    19  -262    -265
    20  -265    -271
    21  -263    -268
    22  -258    -263
    23  -257    -261
    24  -269    -277
    25  -278    -281
    26  -278    -280
    27  -285    -285
```

However, the moving average is not correct. It should look like this:

```
Desired Results     
week    time    moving_average
14      -249    null
15      -267    null
16      -254    null
17      -256    -257
18      -254    -258
19      -262    -257
20      -265    -259
21      -263    -261
22      -258    -262
23      -257    -261
24      -269    -262
25      -278    -266
26      -278    -271
27      -285    -278
```

Can you suggest how I can revise my SQL query to get the accurate moving average as shown in the Desired Results?

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by week:

```
SELECT week, time,
       avg(time) OVER (ORDER BY week ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING) AS moving_average
FROM my_table
ORDER BY week ASC;
```

That still doesn't quite do what you want but it is the more glaring problem.  Based on your sample data, I think you want:

```
SELECT week, time,
       (case when row_number() over (order by week) >= 4
             then avg(time) over (order by week rows between 3 preceding and current row)
        end) as moving_average
FROM my_table
ORDER BY week ASC;
```

Note that you seem to want the preceding three weeks and current row for the moving average -- a little counter-intuitive for a "four-week" moving average.

Comment: Gordon - The first one gets me within rounding errors so that's probably close, although it still gives values for the first three when they should be null. For the second, I get the following error message: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 81'number' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Why subtract number from row?

Comment: Strawberry do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @JohnBarbour . . . That is a typo.  The function is `row_number()`.